# Migrate repositories from Sonatype Nexus 2.8.0-05 to 3.x

Tags: maven, migration, nexus, sonatype

I am trying to migrate our Nexus 2.8.0-05 to 3.x OSS. I tried 3 times and failed to start the nexus server. Even I tried to upgrade step by step from 2.8.0-05 to 2.8.1 and then to 2.9.0. I learnt that I am not on the right track to safely migrate my artefacts to 3.x. So would like to know, is there a way to migrate our 2.8.0-05 to 3.x safely?.
We use
Java,
maven,
ubuntu and jdk 1.8

Comment: Have you read the migration guides from Sonatype for migrating from 2.X to 3.X etc. ? Apart from that really using 2.8.X ? Wow that's very old...

Comment: Yes that's the reason planning to migrate. As this 2.8.0 is running smoothly I am but worried that I should not break the existing

Comment: I would go first to most recent 2.X version...

Answer (score 0):

You must upgrade to the latest version of Nexus Repo 2.x before attempting upgrade to Nexus Repo 3.  Once that is done, you’ll be able to run the migration procedure to go to Nexus Repo 3.  This will create a new instance with your existing data and configuration, you Nexus Repo 2 instance will still be intact and usable during and after the procedure.

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Upgrading#Upgrading-Upgradingfrom2.xto3.y